# Is it possible to un-minify Chrome's heap snapshot results? (like through a source map)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory, snapshot, source-maps, unminify

I'm trying to interpret the results of various heap snapshots on Chrome's dev tools menu for memory leaks but it's hard breaking down some of the code but since it's minified, a lot of the variable and function names aren't very helpful.

Would appreciate any help and ideas!

It seems like it can be done through [Microsoft Edge's memory tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/whats-new/2023/05/devtools-113) but I would like to accomplish something similar through Chrome.